# ReactJs managing an array of stateful components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I have a parent component that I want to use to dynamically add and remove an stateful component, but something weird is happening.

This is my parent component and how I control my list of `FilterBlock`

```
import React from 'react'
import FilterBlock from './components/FilterBlock'

export default function List() {
    const [filterBlockList, setFilterList] = useState([FilterBlock])
    
    const addFilterBlock = () => {
        setFilterList([...filterBlockList, FilterBlock])
    }

    const onDeleteFilterBlock = (index) => {
        const filteredList = filterBlockList.filter((block, i) => i !== index);
        setFilterList(filteredList)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                filterBlockList.map((FilterBlock, index) => (
                    <FilterBlock
                        key={index}
                        onDeleteFilter={() => onDeleteFilterBlock(index)}
                    />
                ))
            }
            <button onClick={addFilterBlock}></button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

You can assume `FilterBlock` is a stateful react hooks component.

My issue is whenever I trigger the `onDeleteFilter` from inside any of the added components, only the last pushed `FilterBlock` gets removed from the list even though I remove it based on its index on the list.

Please check my example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/emad2710/wzh5Lqj9/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're storing component function `FilterBlock` to the state and mutate the parent state inside a child component.

You may know that mutating state directly will cause unexpected bugs. And you're mutating states here:

```
/* Child component */

function FilterBlock(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')
    const options = [
        { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
        { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
        { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
    ]
    const onInputChange = (e) => {
        // child state has been changed, but parent state
        // does not know about it
        // thus, parent state has been mutated
        setValue(e.target.value)
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.onDeleteFilter}>remove</button>
            <input value={value} onChange={onInputChange}></input>
              
        </div>
    )
}

/* Parent component */

const addFilterBlock = () => {
  setFilterList([...filterBlockList, FilterBlock])
}

filterBlockList.map((FilterBlock, index) => (
  <FilterBlock
    key={index}
    onDeleteFilter={() => onDeleteFilterBlock(index)}
  />
))
```

When a FilterBlock value changes, `FilterBlock` will store its state somewhere `List` component cannot control. That means `filterBlockList` state has been mutated. This leads to unpredictable bugs like the above problem.

To overcome this problem, you need to manage the whole state in parent component:

```
const {useCallback, useState} = React;


function FilterBlock(props) {

    const options = [
        { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
        { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
        { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
    ]

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.onDeleteFilter}>remove</button>
            <input value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange}></input>
              
        </div>
    )
}


function App() {
    
    const [values, setValues] = useState(['strawberry']);
    
    const addFilterBlock = useCallback(() => {
            setValues(values.concat(''));
    }, [values]);

    const onDeleteFilterBlock = useCallback((index) => {
        setValues(values.filter((v, i) => i !== index));
    }, [values]);
    
    const setFilterValue = useCallback((index, value) => {
        const newValues = [...values];
        newValues[index] = value;
        setValues(newValues);
    }, [values]);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                values.map((value, index) => (
                    <FilterBlock
                        key={index}
                        onDeleteFilter={() => onDeleteFilterBlock(index)}
                        value={value}
                        onChange={(e) => setFilterValue(index, e.target.value)}
                    />
                ))
            }
            <button onClick={addFilterBlock}>add</button>
        </div>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e210jubm/)

Comment: *child state has been changed, but parent state does not know about it*. That's a fair point. But let's remove `onChange={onInputChange}` from the child component altogether, thereby eliminating the state change. It still won't work. Can you explain that?

Comment: Good point. Still, `FilterBlock` is one same object. You add same object (ref) again and again when you click add button. @codemonkey

Comment: Hmm thanks that makes sense. Yeah I was aware of this solution, but I was hoping there would be a way to have the state managed in the component. So when you say "you add the same object ref" wouldn't it be possible to dynamically create new ref for each of the instances?

Comment: @Emad I am with you on this one. bravemaster's solution makes perfect sense (store values for each index in the parent). But it's the rationale behind why YOUR code does not work is what I am dubious about here.

Comment: @codemonkey @Emad I can't point the exact reason either. Maybe `useRef` can help but I'm not sure. If you want to control states in child components, you should use `react-redux`. Or use `useContext` hook.

Comment: @bravemaster thanks for your time. One other (out of interest) question, what's the reason behind using `useCallback`  in your code example you for all your setState functions?

Comment: @Emad `useCallback` prevents redefinition of functions when states are changed. It redefines function only when states in dependency array has been changed. It's for performance and you can opt out using them.